# Maximal vectors in a finite dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{F})$-module.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modules, representation-theory, lie-algebras, nilpotence

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Consider $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{F})$, with standard basis given by
\begin{equation}
x=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1 \\
0&0
\end{pmatrix},
y=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0 \\
1&0
\end{pmatrix},
h=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0 \\
0&-1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
In the book "Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory" by J.E. Humphrey, a maximal vector is introduced as follows.

Let $(\phi,V)$ be an arbitrary finite dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{F})$-module. The semisimplicity of $h$ implies that $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of eigenspaces $V_{\lambda}=\{v\in V\,|\,h.v=\lambda v\}$, where $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ is an eigenvalue of $\phi(h)$ (but this definition makes sense for arbitrary $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$, its just non-zero if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue). There is a lemma that says that $v\in V_\lambda\implies x.v\in V_{\lambda+2}$, which is trivially proven using the commutation relations. Since $V$ is finite dimensional, there exists some $\lambda\in\mathbb{F}$ such that $V_\lambda\neq0$ but $V_{\lambda+2}=0$, and we say that any $v\in V_\lambda$ is a maximal vector of weight $\lambda$.

Subsequently, there is an exercise which asks you to prove that each arbitrary finite dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{F})$-module has a maximal vector.

Consider the subalgebra spanned $h$ and $x$ (this is actually a hint). It is clear from the commutation relations that this subalgebra is solvable, so there exists a common eigenvector for all elements of this subalgebra. In particular $\phi(h)(v)=\lambda_hv$, $\phi(x)(v)=\lambda_xv$, and $V_{\lambda_h}\neq0$. The nilpotency of $x$ implies the nilpotency of $\phi(x)$, so $\lambda_x=0$ and thus $\phi(x)(v)=0$. That is, $v$ is an maximal vector.

However, we can also say this: Using the finite dimensionality we will find an  $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $V_{\lambda}\neq0$ and $V_{\lambda+2}=0$, and thus a maximal vector. I don't see anything wrong with this argument.

My question is: Is this fact alone enough to ensure the existence of a maximal vector? If not, why not?

It seems to me that the nilpotency of $x$ is important here, yet there seems to be a proof which does not use it. If someone could clarify/comment on this, and perhaps tell me where I went wrong, that would be nice.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by $x$ being nilpotent (do you mean ad-nilpotent perhaps?). But there is no guarantee that $\phi(x)$ is nilpotent in general. For this you need that the module is finite dimensional (there are simple representations of this Lie algebra on which $x$ does not act locally nilpotently, these are just infinite dimensional)

Comment: I assume (and say so) that the module is finite dimensional. $x$ is a nilpotent matrix, since $x^2=0$. It is of course ad-nilpotent.

Comment: But we are not considering the algebra generated by these, we are considering the Lie algebra. Applying the linear map given by $x$ twice is not the same as applying the one given by $x^2$, since this is not an element in the Lie algebra.

Comment: You are of course correct, but I remember now why I say that $\phi(x)$ is nilpotent, sorry: there is a lemma which states that for a semisimple Lie algebra (fin. dim.) and for a fin. dim. representation $(\phi,V)$, $\phi(x)=\phi(s)+\phi(n)$ is the Jordan dec. of $\phi(x)$ is $x=s+n$ is the abstract Jordan dec.. Hence, $\phi(x)$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Sure, that also gives that it is nilpotent, again using the finite dimensionality of the representation. My main objection with the original was that you seemed to be arguing that it was nilpotent without using that fact (the fact that applying $x$ increases the weight by $2$ also implies that it is nilpotent, again using that the dimension is finite).

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "Using the finite dimensionality we will find an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $V_{\lambda+2n} \neq 0$ and $V_{\lambda +2}=0$, and thus a maximal vector." Could you explain this?

Comment: We cannot have an infinite chain of eigenspaces, because V is finite dimensional.

Comment: @B. Pasternak Did you happen to find the answer for this later (seeing that the question is three years old)? I mean I am also stuck on the same problem now.

Comment: Which part exactly?